# Enable KSM on active hypervisor

Tags: linux, debian, qemu, kvm

Simple question: Is it dangerous to activate [KSM](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/ksm.txt) on a running hypervisor (Debian 8 with 3.16 kernel)?

Or is it recommended to shut down all virtual machines (KVM/qemu) first, then activate KSM and then start the virtual machines again?

We expect a memory saving of approx. 50% (we have a similar system where KSM is already active and there we effectively save almost 50% due to the always very similar VM appliances).

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [sf].

Comment: My fault, sorry! I just flagged the question for deletion. Thank you